# UDP-Paket and Payload

Tags: switch-statement, udp, router, payload

I am currently studying for an exam and I came across this question.

Given is the Internet shown. The occurring local network work with switches. Computer A sends to computer H a UDP packet with the payload "ABCD". Show the essential parts of the Ethernet package leaving Computer A. Explain on all subordinate network levels how the payload of the UDP packet is routed in detail to computer H. Explain which network component makes which changes to the package. How many local Networks are there? How many switches are there?

I came up with an answer but I have a feeling I am missing something crucial.

[image]

This is my answer:

Computer A knows the IP Address of computer H. So it creates an IP-Packet wrapped in an Ethernet Frame with the Payload string "ABCD" and the header of the frame has the mac address of the local gateway (the router). So computer A sends it and it reaches the switch. The switch looks at the header and sends it to the router because it knows the port and the mac address of the router. Computer F is the Router because it has two IP addresses (and also two mac adresses for each local host.) Router F opens the IP-Paket and Ethernet Frame and sees that Computer H is not in it's local network. So it creates an new ethernetframe and puts the IP_Paket and the payload inside. The destination mac address of the frame is now changed it is now the mac adress of router G. We repeat the process and this time it reaches Computer G. Computer G (the router ) looks at the header and sees that computer h is in it's local network. If Computer G knows the Mac Address of Computer H it will send it to Computer H otherwise the Router will send an Arp Request. If it sends and Arp Request all the other Computers will get the message and H will send an arp response and G will send the Paket. Computer H will open the ethernet Frame and the Paket with the payload ABCD.

I think there are 3 local networks and three switches.

This would be my answer.

Comment: your answer is correct

Comment: @DZDomi thank you for your reply. even the 3 switches are correct?

Comment: yes otherwise the computers in each subnet ABC/DEF/GHI have no way of communicating with each other

Comment: @DZDomi thank you, one final question does the TTL (Time to live ) play a role while sending udp packets?

Comment: TTL works on layer 3 (ip) of the osi model so it has nothing to do with udp/tcp, as they are on layer 4; so to answer your question it plays no special role in udp